# Enabling Cuda on Azure Datascience VM

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow

1. Azure Datascience VM with Nvidia Gpu extension
2. Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
   Python 3.5.5
3. NVCC V10.0.130
4. Tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1

When runnning an op, I get

> E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:300] failed call to
>   cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Answer (score 0):

what is the size of the VM you are using on Azure ?